# SQL query to count each person's longest string of consecutive scores of 7

Tags: sql-server, sql, ssms

I've got a SQL table that looks like this (with the name in column A and the score in column B):

```
 N.  Name  Score
 1.  Jim   7   
 2.  Jim   4   
 3.  Jim   4   
 4.  Jim   7
 5.  Jim   7
 6.  Jim   7
 7.  Jim   7
 8.  Jim   4
 9.  Ted   4
 10. Ted   4
 11. Ted   7
 12. Ted   7
 .
 .
 .
 n. cont'd
```

I need to rank each person by their highest number of consecutive results of 7.

Jim's max 7 result: 4, because he got a score of 7 four times in a row. Ted's max 7 result 2; that's his maximum number. If I were searching for max 4s, their scores would both be two.

How do I get the SQL query function in SSMS to tell me what the longest string of scores of 7 (or any given value) was for each person?

This is a sample of a long list, over 100 million rows, with 1 million unique names (they're actually unique numbers, not names, but for illustrative purposes...).

Ideally, the query will return a list that looks like this:

Bob 133
Jane 117
Phil 106
...
Jim 4
Ted 2

So I think it will begin with SELECT DISTINCT, so my result has all unique names.

Comment: When you get a moment, look over [The Difference Between ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), and DENSE_RANK()](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/)

Comment: Thanks, when I said I need to rank them by high / low, what I should have said was, I'd like to know know what the maximum number of consecutive scores is for each person, and I intend to then rank those values high to low. This just seems to create a list without getting the value.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You should clarify, "longest string of scores of 7",  consecutive string or just the total amount of scores higher then 7?

Comment: I'm looking for a SQL query to count each person's longest string of consecutive scores of 7. Title renamed accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I've come up with.  You could potentially put this into one big query, but I broke it out in to temp tables for clarity's sake so you can adapt it more easily.  Basically you'll need a multi-step process

1. Filter the data
2. Externally group the records
3. Create relational groups and count the results

**Code**

```
 --Test data
 create table #testRank
 (
      RowNum int identity
    , Name   nvarchar(255)
    , Score  int
 )

 insert #testRank
 values   ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',4)
        , ('Jim',4)
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',4)
        , ('Ted',4)
        , ('Ted',4)
        , ('Ted',7)
        , ('Ted',7)
        -- I've added a second set of Jim data for testing
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',7)
        , ('Jim',7)

--minimize the dataset; if your dealing with millions of rows, filter out the scores less than 7
select RowNum, Name 
into #smallerDataSet
from #testRank where score = 7;

--create groups or strings delineated by NULL values indicating the start and end of the string of scores about 7
select 
      x.RowNum
    , x.Name
    , Case when z.NextRow is null then null else x.RowNum-1 end PrevRow
    , Case when y.PrevRow is null then null else x.RowNum+1 end NextRow
into #strings
from #smallerDataSet x
    Left Join (select RowNum-1 PrevRow, Name from #smallerDataSet) y on y.PrevRow = x.RowNum and y.Name = x.Name
    Left Join (select RowNum+1 NextRow, Name from #smallerDataSet) z on z.NextRow = x.RowNum and z.Name = x.Name
Where PrevRow is not null or NextRow is not null

--visulaize the query above
select * from #strings

--use the ROW_NUMBER function to seperate the groups from each other; particularly important when the same name has the same string count
--then simply do the math and order the list
Select Distinct p.Name, EndStr-StartStr+1 MaxString
from
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by RowNum) GroupNum, Name, RowNum StartStr 
    from #strings
    where PrevRow is null
) p
join
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by RowNum) GroupNum, Name, RowNum EndStr
    from #strings
    where NextRow is null
) n on n.GroupNum = p.GroupNum and n.Name = p.Name
order by MaxString desc

drop table #strings
drop table #smallerDataSet
drop table #testRank
```

Comment: First, thank you so much for writing this out. It is saying invalid column name for lines 53 and 54 for PrevRow, RowNum, Name, and NextRow  and I cannot figure out why. I am running the script all together, and have previously run in pieces and found success in creating the #Strings. Could there be a missing comma or something?

Comment: The code works on the test data I posted. You'll need to modify it to work on your tables scheme. RowNum represents the values in your example for N.

Comment: This is great. I am running it now. I did a 100 row run and it is returning every string greater than two, rather than the highest one for each "person." That's kind of an unexpected benefit, but that means a single person's name will likely show up many times instead of just once with the greatest value. It also returned the temporary tables. I'm worried that means it will keep everything in RAM and crash before it finishes writing to file. I imagine this will be a very long job, so please share any insights if you currently have them; otherwise I will post if and when this is successful.

Comment: Never mind Steve. It only took 20 min to write to file. These are champagne problems. HUGE thank you!

Comment: The temp table selects are for your benefit. Just comment them out unless you need them for trouble shooting